# how to make calculator in JQuery when we add new equation that remove old eval value and replace a new button value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, calculator

I am trying to replace the answer value with new value in my jQuery calculator, but it does not replace the answer. Rather, it adds to next of the answer.

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($("#preview").val() + $("#btn1").val())
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($("#preview").val() + $("#btn2").val())
});
$("#btn4").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($("#preview").val() + $("#btn4").val())
});
$("#btn5").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($("#preview").val() + $("#btn5").val())
});
$("#btn6").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($("#preview").val() + $("#btn6").val())
});
$("#btn7").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($("#preview").val() + $("#btn7").val())
});
$("#btn8").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($('#preview').val().substring(0, $('#preview').val().length - 1));
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val((eval($("#preview").val())))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="preview">
<input type="button" type="button" id="btn1" value="3" onclick="showValue()">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="4">
<input type="button" id="btn4" value="*">
<input type="button" id="btn5" value="+">
<input type="button" id="btn6" value="-">
<input type="button" id="btn7" value="/">
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="=">
<input type="button" id="btn8" value="bs">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a global variable that is equal to `true` when the answer is evaluated. Also, your code can be simplified like below:

```js
let evaluated = false;

$(".input").click(function() {
  const val = evaluated ? $(this).val() : ($("#preview").val() + $(this).val())
  $("#preview").val(val)
  evaluated = false;
});

$("#btn8").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val($('#preview').val().substring(0, $('#preview').val().length - 1));
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
  $("#preview").val((eval($("#preview").val())))
  evaluated = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="preview">
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="input" value="3">
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="input" value="4">
<input type="button" id="btn4" class="input" value="*">
<input type="button" id="btn5" class="input" value="+">
<input type="button" id="btn6" class="input" value="-">
<input type="button" id="btn7" class="input" value="/">
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="=">
<input type="button" id="btn8" value="bs">
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: how to addition new value with answer value in JQuery?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean how can plus, minus, divide, and multiple with first equation answer in the calculator. if I plus value with equation answer it replaces it.

Comment: You can add a new class to these operators and in the click handler, let it ignore `evaluated` value if the class belongs to it.